# how to copy the results from existing class and insert into another class using sparql

Tags: java, rdf, sparql, jena

I am using sparql to get the data of one graph.My requirement is to copy those results and insert into another graph.

Below is my sparql query to get the data of one graph:

```
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
prefix ctag: <http://s.opencalais.com/1/type/tag/>
prefix c: <http://s.opencalais.com/1/pred/>
construct {
  ?tag c:name ?name ;
       c:importance ?importance .
}
where {
  ?tag a ctag:SocialTag ;
       c:name ?name ;
       c:importance ?importance .
}
```

executing above query i am getting SocialTag related name and importance.now i am trying to copy those results and insert into another graph(Industry).how to do this.please suggest me.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

See SPARQL Update and the INSERT operation.